# Remove a comment after an edit

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

There was a typo in a post that I edited here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761801/3385432

(The number `-1944` should have been `-1943` as pointed out by a comment.)

The comment is now no longer needed. Flagging the comment doesn't seem appropriate. Is it possible to delete this comment since it is no longer needed?

Comment: _Is it possible to delete this comment since it is no longer needed?_ **No.** _You_ cannot delete the comment of other users. You can flag that as _obsolete(outdated)_. Three flags and it'll be deleted.

Answer (score 7):

You should flag that comment as "obsolete".

From [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> ## When should I flag a comment?
>
> - obsolete — for example, criticism of a post that has been satisfactorily addressed by the author